# build R package--lines wider than 100 characters

Tags: r, package

When checking our new R package, we sometimes get NOTE "lines wider than 100 characters. These lines will be truncated in the PDF manual."

Do we have to fix this? If so, how do you usually fix it?

Comment: Generally, "notes" are not *must fixes*. You should look at the PDF manual and see if you care about the problem. Line breaks are a good solution.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In the example part, how to break the line without getting errors?

Comment: The same way you would break the line in a script. Are you using Roxygen for doc generation? I would recommend looking at existing packages. Say, look at the [multi-line examples in `?ggplot2::geom_point`](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/geom-point.r)

Comment: They aren't all multiline, but some are (see the one that is commented *"You can create interesting shapes by layering multiple points..."*. Even if you're not using Roxygen you can see [how the .Rd files look](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/man/geom_point.Rd).

Comment: But literally every R package on CRAN [is mirrored on github](https://github.com/cran), so there is no shortage of examples.

Comment: Thanks Gregor! Those are helpful sources!