# Best practice for handling code more than 100 characters wide on CRAN and for CRAN checks?

Tags: r, cran, roxygen2

CRAN doesn't like lines of more than 100 characters in width, but sometimes code makes (much) more sense being that wide, for example, urls.

To satisfy CRAN checks (and the other things that depend on those checks, for example CI tools like Travis CI), I have split long strings into two and pasted them together, here's an example

```
mystring <- paste0("The quick brown fox ",
  "jumps over the lazy dog")
```

which is far less elegant and less natural than

```
mystring <- "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
```

Is there some standard way to keep code natural but satisfy CRAN checks?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39009635/build-r-package-lines-wider-than-100-characters) discussion. I don't think there's been much progress on this question, as of late.

Comment: @InfiniteFlashChess I guess 'notes' are quite harmless, but there are some flow on effects, for example, continuous integration software kindly picks up on our human mistakes, so will notify of a failed build even if just one note is present, which is a great thing (to aspire code free of any error/warning/note). I just wonder if rather than ignore the symptom, can we write prevent the note with better code. We could always set CI tools to not worry about notes, but then we may risk missing some genuinely helpful notes in the future

Comment: can you be a little more specific about where the warnings are occurring, and whether they're WARNINGs or NOTEs? (Does your Travis build really fail on NOTEs? I think mine only fail on warnings ...)  I think this is in the context of documentation, right?

Comment: You're talking about this NOTE, right? https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/tools/R/check.R#L2152-L2156

Comment: An example would be great, if you have one.